# Is there a Windows (Phone) equivalent of the Android selector?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, windows-phone, win-universal-app

Android xml has a nice thing for button (and other things) states which are selectors.

Here is an example of the Android Documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize=["true" | "false"]
    android:dither=["true" | "false"]
    android:variablePadding=["true" | "false"] >
    <item
        android:drawable="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource"
        android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_hovered=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_activated=["true" | "false"]
        android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
</selector>
```

Is there something in XAML or C# we can use to obtain the same effect on Windows (Phone) apps. (Or Universal Apps for that matter).

Nowadays I use the Listeners GotFocus, LostFocus, etc. But i don't think it is a straghtforward solution.

Anyone has a better idea on how to do this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @user2941906 The document you provided is for WPF. Probably there is something similar for Windows (Phone)/runtime/universal apps. But that's not really that

Comment: I think styling XAML in windows phone is same like a wpf

Comment: @user2941906 There are several controls and features that you have on WPF that are not available for Windows Phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a complete multi-state layout of a control purely in xaml.
Define a custom style for button and set the `Template` property. Unfortunately this completely overrides the template, so you would probably have to copy the default one. There you can set different `VisualStates` for `Pressed`, `MouseOver` etc.

To get the button default style use Blend as described here: http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/windows-phone-button-default-style

More info on custom button templates: http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/custom-styles-and-templates-in-windows-phone-button

Comment: I have wondered about that solution as well. It is a shame that you have to copy/paste the entire default style and cannot only override some VisualStates :(